# Python not calling Jython using 'subprocess' module

Tags: python, jython

I'm trying to call a Jython script from a Python file.

I've the **Jython file: `testing.py`**, which contains:

```
print "Hello"
```

Then, I've the **Python file `caller.py`** that contains:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['jython', 'testing.py'])
```

If I execute the python file that calls the jython script, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrador\workspace\Interfaz\bashpython.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['jython', 'testing.py'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 486, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] El sistema no puede hallar el archivo especificado
```

The thing is that if I change the caller.py function to call it to another Python function instead of a Jython one, works perfectly (it prints the `Hello`string):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'testing.py'])
```

I'm using Eclipse Standard 4.3.1. and PyDev.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happen if you specify the absolute path of the `jython`? `r'C:\path\to\jython.exe'`

Comment: Which is the exact command? `subprocess.call(['C:\path\to\jython.exe', 'testing.py'])` ? That at least is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should specify the actual path of the jython for thr first item of the list.

Answer (score 0):

If `testing.py` and `caller.py` are in same folder then the above code should work. But if they are not in same location then it is obvious that you have to provide the location of the file.

I have `caller.py` in `/home/reuben/caller.py` and `testing.py` in `/home/reuben/Documents/testing.py` . And I have given the full path of testing.py in caller.py.

```
subprocess.call(['jython', '/home/reuben/Documents/testing.py'])
```

And all that is working for me.